# Detect if any video is playing in a webpage using Jquery or/and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

My purpose is detected if one of the two videos are playing and console.log it.
I try to build dynamic videos play detect.
I read video ID when the user clicks on the play button, and then use the video ID to assign it video for addEventListner but it just works with my first video. the second video doesn't work and

```
$(function(){

     var videoid = "";

    $('video').bind('play', function (e) {
        videoid = $(this).attr('id');
    });

   $('video').on("click", function() {
   // test if global variable work
            console.log(videoid);
   });

  var abc = 'video1';

  document.getElementById(videoid).addEventListener('playing', function(){
    console.log('play' + videoid);
  })
  document.getElementById(videoid).addEventListener('pause', function(){
    console.log('3443');
  })

  document.getElementById(videoid).addEventListener('ended', function(){
    console.log('242434');
  })

});
```

what did I wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/fbc7nn0o/51/

Comment: The `video` variable in the global scope has not been defined, and thus will fall on `document.getElementById(variableName) || document.getElementsByName(variable) || undefined` so `addEventListener` will only be called from the first `<video>` element, which as the `id` video... What you want is `$('video').on({ play : onplay, playing: onplaying, pause: onpause...})` where `onplay`, `onplaying` `onpause` ... are event handlers functions (`function onplaying(e){$('.text').fadeOut();
console.log('dfdgd');}`). Also note that `$('#'+$(this).attr('id'))[0]` is perfect non-sense. Just use `this`.

Comment: @Kaiido This comment should be an answer (lol! I'm more used to say the opposite!) ;)

Comment: I fixed the global variable, my goal is deal with multiple videos.

Comment: I still can not make it work in my goal, if i assign document.getElementById(abc) it work but this just deal with only one and not dynamic. it not work with document.getElementById(videoid) with videoid is a global variable. 
I played with @Kaiido code $('video').on({
  play : console.log('play'),
  playing: console.log('playing'),
  pause: console.log('pause')
}); but it run at the begin and I can not add click even.

Answer (score 4):

The `video` variable in the global scope has not been defined, and thus will fall on `document.getElementById(variableName) || document.getElementsByName(variable) || undefined` (cf [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)).

So `addEventListener` will only be called from the first `<video>` element, which as the `id` `"video"`...

What you want is

```
$('video').on({
  play : onplay,
  playing: onplaying,
  pause: onpause
  ...
})
```

where `onplay`, `onplaying`, `onpause` ... are event handlers functions. e.g `function onplaying(e){ $('.text').fadeOut(); console.log('dfdgd'); }`.

Also note that `$('#'+$(this).attr('id'))[0]` is perfect non-sense. 
Just use `this`.

Answer (score 0):

It work for me.

```
$('video').bind('play', function (e) {

    var videoid = $(this).attr('id');

    document.getElementById(videoid).addEventListener('playing', function(){
        console.log('play' + videoid);
    });
    document.getElementById(videoid).addEventListener('pause', function(){
        console.log('3443');
    });

    document.getElementById(videoid).addEventListener('ended', function(){
        console.log('ended');
    });

});
```